# Haskell: Parsing String to Custom Type

Tags: haskell

I have declared a type:

```
type Foo = (Char, Char, Char)
```

And want to be able to parse a 3 letter string "ABC" to produce an output Foo with each of ABC as the three attributes of the type.

My current attempt is;

```
parseFoo :: String → Maybe Foo
parseFoo str = f where
    f (a, _, _) = str[0]
    f (_, b, _) = str[1]
    f (_, _, c) = str[2]
```

This is returning an error:

```
Illegal operator ‘→’ in type ‘String → Maybe Foo’
Use TypeOperators to allow operators in types
```

My question is:

- How do I prevent this error on compilation?
- Am I even on the right track?

Comment: There are sevaral problems here: first of all you seem to do the opposite: print the `Foo` type to a string, furthermore the patterns you describe are *irrefutabled*: it will always match the *first* element.

Comment: Do you want to store the first three characters of a string into a `Foo`?

Comment: Yes I am trying to store the first three characters of a string (Which will always be three characters) into a Foo - as for the first comment, I can see now obviously that is a big error on my part - not sure it explains the error I am returning though

Comment: You seem to be new to Haskell. I'd recommend reading through the entirety of [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) before diving in further. If you'd read that, you probably wouldn't be having to ask this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand it the correct way, you want to store the first three characters of a string into a type `Foo` (which is an alias for a 3-tuple that contains three `Char`s).

The signature seems correct (it is good practice to return a `Maybe` if something can go wrong, and here it is possible that the string contains less than three characters). A problem hwever is that you write an arrow character `→` whereas signatures in Haskell usse `->` (two ASCII characters, a dash and a greater than symbol).

So we can define the signature as:

```
parseFoo :: String -> Maybe Foo
```

Now the second problem is that you here *define* a function `f` that maps `Foo`s to `String`s, so the reverse. You also make use of a syntax that is frequently used for indexing in languages of the C/C++/C#/Java programming language family, but indexing in Haskell is done with the `(!!)` operator, and since you define the function in reverse, it will not help.

A string is a *list* of `Char`s, so:

```
type String = [Char]
```

We can thus define two patterns:

1. a list with three (or more) characters; and
2. a list with less than three characters.

For the former, we return a 3-tuple with these characters (wrapped in a `Just`), for the latter we return `Nothing`:

```
parseFoo :: String -> Maybe Foo
parseFoo (a:b:c:_) = Just (a, b, c)
parseFoo _ = Nothing
```

Or if we do not want to parse strings with more than three characters successfully:

```
parseFoo :: String -> Maybe Foo
parseFoo [a, b, c] = Just (a, b, c)
parseFoo _ = Nothing
```

Comment: This was a perfect explanation - very much appreciated